# Exportation of Access file table to Excel spreadsheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dao

I am trying the following code to import data in an active worksheet using VBA, with an Access file as a source.

The Access table to import is called "Table01", I have a error message when defining the query (Set daoQueryDef = daoDB.QueryDefs(Text)): "item not found in this collection".

Do you know where is the problem? In the synthax?

```
Sub Import()

Dim daoDB As DAO.Database
Dim daoQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim daoRcd As DAO.Recordset

Set daoDB = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Desktop\Database\Database.mdb")>
Text = "SELECT * FROM `Table01`"
Set daoQueryDef = daoDB.QueryDefs(Text)

Set daoRcd = daoQueryDef.OpenRecordset
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset daoRcd

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `Set daoQueryDef = daoDB.QueryDefs(Text)` line.  There is no `QueryDef` already existing with a name equal to the value of `Text`.  You need to use `CreateQueryDef` to define it.

```
Set daoQueryDef = daoDB.CreateQueryDef("TempQueryDef", Text) 
Set daoRcd = daoQueryDef.OpenRecordset
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset daoRcd
daoDB.QueryDefs.Delete dao.QueryDef.Name
```

This method creates a new `QueryDef` with `Text` as its SQL string and opens it as a recordset, does the copy and then removes it from the `QueryDefs` collection at the end.

See Microsoft's website for further examples, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx

EDIT (better): Using a temp QueryDef without needing to delete it afterwadrs (thanks Remou)

```
Set daoQueryDef = daoDB.CreateQueryDef("", Text) 
Set daoRcd = daoQueryDef.OpenRecordset
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset daoRcd
```

Comment: If you use an empty string for the querydef name, you can still work with the querydef, but it will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

It's working, here's the working code:

```
Sub Import()

Dim daoDB As DAO.Database
Dim daoQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim daoRcd As DAO.Recordset

Set daoDB = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Desktop\Database\Database.mdb")>
Text = "SELECT * FROM `Table01`"

Set daoQueryDef = daoDB.CreateQueryDef("", Text)    
Set daoRcd = daoQueryDef.OpenRecordset
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset daoRcd

End Sub
```